# java exception: No FileSystem for scheme

Tags: java, hadoop, jar

The code below copy's data from my local machine to hdfs

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();                   
conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

fs.moveFromLocalFile(new Path("/path/to/file"), new Path("/path/to/hdfs/"));
```

When I run this in eclipse, it works perfectly. However, after I compile to jar and run as stand alone using this code:

```
nohup java -cp "Test.jar" Test &
```

I get the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2584)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)
at Test.main(Test.java:37)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a classpath issue. The common approach used for adding classpath is as below:

```
export CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/\*
```

Unfortunately this didn't work for me. This is what worked. I had to add the path containing all my jar files to the nohup java command..

```
nohup java -cp "/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*:Test.jar" Test &
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that Test.jar is a fat JAR (including the dependencies) something is going wrong with the registration of the protocol handlers.

To override this if you know the package in Hadoop that provides it do something like (this is a random, and very likely wrong, guess):

```
nohup java -cp Test.jar -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.hadoop.fs Test &
```

That will work if **org.apache.hadoop.fs.Handler** exists and extends **java.net.URLStreamHandler**.

This mechanism is described in more detail in [the JavaDocs for java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String)).

An [alternative fix](http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/no-filesystem-for-scheme-hdfs/#post-52187) is documented on the HortonWorks forum.

Comment: I think I did that. But I still get the same issue. I am using cloudera.. This is what I did:export CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/hadoop/client/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*

Comment: @FreeMan take another look. You only included Test.jar (`-cp Test.jar`).  You need to incude the other JARs in that command line separated by **:** since you appear to on a *nix OS (like Ubuntu, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, SmartOS).

Comment: actually, Test.jar contains all the jar files I used to run it in eclipse. I exported my java program as a runnable JAR file.

Comment: Okay, that's very strange.  It may not contain the necessary META-INF content to register the FS scheme.  I remember this being fiddly when a colleague did it to support SFTP.

Comment: @FreeMan I think my workaround may work, although it seems very wrong for it to be needed.  It really suggests that the Test.jar's META-INF is being mangled when it is merged from all the dependencies.

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Handler doesn't exist

Comment: @FreeMan indeed.  It was a guess.  There should be a **Handler** class somewhere in the hadoop JAR.  Try Ctrl-Shift-T (or Command-Shift-T on OS X) to Open Type and type Handler and see where it is.  If it is isnmt there then Hadoop is using some other mechanism to register the protocol handler.

Comment: FWIW I'm shooting fron the hip, on my smartphone, from a hospital bed, in surgical recovery.  My mileage may vary ;)

Comment: it actually: org.apache.hadoop.util.protocols.. I tried but I get the same error..

Comment: This seems kind of pathological.  I added a link to a solution on the HortonWorks forum.  Try that if you get a chance.  It involves separately referring to the hadoop JARs (even though you've combined them).